# Trying to write Python code to count the number of different vowels in a string?

Tags: python, count

I've literally just started learning to code so very inexperienced, and I probably haven't done this the best way - I'm trying to write code in Python that will count the number of DIFFERENT vowels in a string (i.e. if the input was 'Hello my name is Simon' the output should be '4' as the string contains a, e, i and o)

```
a="a"
A="A"
e="e"
E="E"
i="i"
I="I"
o="o"
O="O"
u="u"
U="U"
num_of_diff_vowels=0
print("This program will count the number of vowels in your string")
ans = input("Enter string here:")
if a or A in ans:
    num_of_diff_vowels=num_of_diff_vowels+1
if e or E in ans:
    num_of_diff_vowels=num_of_diff_vowels+1
if o or O in ans:
    num_of_diff_vowels=num_of_diff_vowels+1
if i or I in ans:
    num_of_diff_vowels=num_of_diff_vowels+1
if u or U in ans:
    num_of_diff_vowels=num_of_diff_vowels+1

print(num_of_diff_vowels)
```

So far with this code all I'm getting in the output is '5'...
Any ideas of how to refine this and actually make it work?

Comment: Hint: `if x or y in ans` does not do what you think.

Comment: And an easier way would be to make all the text lowercase, place the characters in a set, filter out non-vowels, then check the size of the set.

Comment: On another note, you don't even need all of those variables for the vowels. And to avoid comparing against upper and lowercase values, I would convert the input string to one or the other.

Comment: `len([e for e in list('aeiou') if e in ans.lower()])` does what you want in one line.

Answer (score 0):

All you `if`'s are always true because they don't do what you think they do. You must change them to

```
if a in ans or A in ans
```

and so on.